# Explain groovy docs on autowrapping (primitives and wrappers)

Tags: java, groovy

The following is an excerpt from the Groovy docs' [Differences from Java](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html) section:

10. Primitives and wrappers

Because Groovy uses Objects for everything, it autowraps references to primitives. Because of this, it does not follow Java’s behavior of widening taking priority over boxing. Here’s an example using int

```
int i
m(i)

void m(long l) {           
  println "in m(long)"
}

void m(Integer i) {        
  println "in m(Integer)"
}
```

There isn't much of an explanation for this. I can't paste it into `groovysh` and show any effect either.

I'm really new Groovy and trying to understand a use-case for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much a "use-case" type thing as just defining what the behavior is. In the example you posted, both method `m`s are valid things to call with `i` as an argument, so the compiler needs to pick one.

In Java, it will prefer *widening* (converting a numeric type to a larger numeric type,  eg. `int` to `long`) over *boxing* (putting a primitive (non-object) type into an object box, eg. `int` to `Integer`). So the equivalent code in Java would execute the method that takes a `long`.

However, in Groovy, primitives are already wrapped in their Object equivalent, so there's no boxing that needs to happen. That means that the `Integer` method is treated as an exact match, and so is chosen over the `long` version.

There's no real advantage to doing it one way over the other; all they're doing is defining what the behavior is so that it's not undefined behavior which version gets called. And it gets special notice in that section of the docs because the behavior that makes the most sense (and is most consistent) in Groovy is different than what happens in Java.

Comment: Very illuminating explanation. I don't actually know much Java - is it common to cast primitives to `Integer` to get the Object features?

Comment: No, but Java will do it automatically if it can only find a method that takes an object

Comment: @maxpleaner the most common reason it's used is in generics, since they can't use primitives. But, as tim_yates says, Java will mostly take care of it automatically.